# Error when updating spyder to 5.0.0 with Anaconda on two different computers

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I updated spyder to 5.0.0 using anaconda prompt shell : First I executed "conda update anaconda", then "conda install spyder=5.0.0". It updated it to 5.0.0, but at each spyder opening, an error message pop-up : [The error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4p8A.png) . I updated spyder anaconda on two different computer, and the problem appear on both computers.

Thanks for reading me, and sorry for my English I'm french.